# Logging into TFS on a Mac

Tags: xcode, command-line, tfs, cordova, team-explorer

I got Team Explorer Everywhere so we can use TFS on the Mac Mini we got to test Iphone apps.  Since we're using XCode for phonegap, we need to use the commandline program and it is giving me a lot of grief.

What I've done so far (Listing out for anyone who stumbles on this so they can use it):

-Downloaded the trial (free)

-Set the path using PATH=$PATH\:/FOLDERLOCATION

-Accepted EULA and got trial product key... for command line program (tf eula/tf productkey -trial)

-Set up workspace:

```
tf workspace -new WORKSPACENAME -server:http://SERVERNAME:PORT/FILEPATH -comment:"WORKSPACENAME" && prompted for username -> domain -> password
```

-Trying to setup the folder path (Fixed):

```
tf workfold -map SERVERFOLDERPATH LOCALFOLDERPATH -collection:http://SERVERNAME:PORT/FILEPATH -workspace:WORKSPACENAME  && prompted for username -> domain -> password
```

-Make sure I can check out/check in (On hold):...

The error I'm getting right now is "An argument error occurred: First free argument must be a server path."  [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsgeneral/thread/d41e2eda-7996-45dc-b457-e9c897f33199) is what I've been following ever since I got the path set, but I think the versions are different because mine doesn't seem to be set up the same.  Any help at all would be appreciated, and I'll keep up with the post as I figure parts out because there doesn't seem to be much online that I can find on TFS on macs.

Update: As normal, I'm an idiot.  Have to put the options at the end of the command and have to have the serverfolder path as the first thing after -map.  Now I just need to figure out how to use the damn thing.  I'll post any other questions I have and try to get all the correct commands up for the selfish reason of having them somewhere in case I forget them later.

Update 2: The mapping hasn't worked out as well as I'd hoped, it seems a combination of my unfamiliarity with Unix/Mac file systems and some settings being missing is keeping me from using 'tf get' to load all of the test data I was trying to get.  I'm planning on trying again after I get the location of where my boss wants the data saved and after I can look into something that would save the workspace so it won't say that it can't find the map path every time...

Comment: Once I get everything working correctly I plan on rewording the opening post and putting the 'answer' part in a response so I can mark it as accepted (unless someone comes along with a helpful answer first of course).  I'm pretty sure it will be a while before I get it working though :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're setting up your workspace and some working folder mappings just fine, after the edit.  If you're having problems doing a `tf get` after this, then there are some common problems that might be occurring.  TFS workspaces can be a little bit opaque and having a better understanding of them can sometimes help you understand where the problem is:

- Team Foundation Server requires a workspace to be configured before you can get files out of source control, edit them or check them back in.  A workspace basically simply contains working folder mappings that map your local path(s) to server path(s).
- Workspaces are stored on the server and are uniquely identified by your computer's hostname, your username and the workspace's name.  A cache of this information for the local host is saved on the client.  This implies:

  1. If you remove a workspace on the server, your workstation will be unable to connect.
  2. If you remove the cache, your local computer will not be able to identify the workspace based on working folder mappings until the cache is rebuilt (which happens every time you connect to the server.)
  3. If you change your username or local workstation's name, you cannot access those workspaces.

     (Note that very early versions of the Teamprise command line client had certain issues on Mac OS that made identifying the local workstation name difficult.  This is fixed, however, in Team Explorer Everywhere.)
- Because you can have multiple workspaces for a single server on a single workstation, you can't always simply provide server paths to `tf` commands, since server paths are ambiguous.  (`$/` exists in every workspace, for example.)  So the command line client resolves paths based on the current working directory and/or the arguments provided.  Meaning that you can run `tf get foo.txt` if you're in a working folder, or you can run `tf get /tmp/foo.txt` if `/tmp` is mapped.

One more point - the configuration data for Team Explorer Everywhere is shared between the TFS plug-in for Eclipse and the command line client.  So if you're more comfortable using a GUI to set up your workspace(s), you can do that and then use the CLC as you see fit.  You don't need to be a Java programmer to use Eclipse - simply download Eclipse and install the TFS plug-in for Eclipse into it, and select Window > Open Perspective > Team Foundation Server Exploring.  After that, you'll have the full GUI Team Explorer experience and this perspective will be restored when you open Eclipse, so you won't even need to worry about the Java IDE bits if you don't want to.

Comment: Thank you!  It took me a while to get it working because our mac is temperamental, but I finally got TFS up in Eclipse.  It looks like I can do everything but add, check-in and check-out in Eclipse, so after we have a proper discussion about how to set up the file system for the native app project I'll get something setup to help with that.  Thanks again!